# How to convert html page to wml page

Tags: html, wml

I have an html static page as well as a url of html web page
Can anybody suggest me how can i convert these html webpages to a wml web page?

any converter? or any way to achieve this?
any solution that can be done at client end or server end will be acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would urge you to re-consider. There are a number of issues with WML, and many are dealt with in this page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Application_Protocol#Criticism

If you are determined to convert mark-up to WML however, your best bet would be writing an XSL file that takes well-formed XHTML and transforms it into WML.

Comment: can u please suggest any tutorial...I cannot find a way to achieve it

Comment: A tutorial for what? XSL transformations? Google is your friend. With regards WML / HTML, the basic difference is round the use of the `card` entity, and a stricter doctype. If your mark-up is clean, you shouldn't have too many issues converting. Really depends on the nature of the HTML you're dealing with.